# How can I make the sticky element in my HTML form remain visible on screens smaller than 800px using JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, element, sticky

In the header I have a element ID homezipform which contains the two inputfields zipcode and house number, with a call to action. I want to make it sticky to the bottom of the page when scrolling down the page. It works on anything with a screen 800px or more, however if the screen goes 800px and lower the sticky element does not show. What causes that? Here is the code I used:

```
<div class="page_zip"></div>
<p></p>
          <div class="zip_form">
          <form id="homezipform" action="../quote/">
          <input type="text" class="zip_input_smaller" id="zip_input" name="zip_input" placeholder="Your zipcode" />
          <input type="text" class="zip_input_nr" id="huisnummerinputpage" name="huisnummerinputpage" placeholder="House number" />
          <input type="submit" class="zip_submit" value="GO" />
          </form>
          <div class="subzip_info_page">Receive quotations</div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>

// Get the form element by ID
var form = document.getElementById("homezipform");

// Get the offset position of the form
var formOffset = form.offsetTop;

// Function to add the "sticky" class to the form when scrolling
function stickyForm() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= formOffset) {
    form.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    form.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

// Add the event listeners to check for scrolling
window.addEventListener("scroll", stickyForm);
window.addEventListener("touchmove", stickyForm);

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

I tried using media queries for the css to show it below 640px or 800px or lower and that also did not work. I also tried to use the window.addEventListener("touchmove", stickyForm) with no effect.

Comment: Have you done some debugging to check the values of things within your "stickyForm()" function?  It would probably be useful to also include the HTML code, so that others can understand fully what your page is doing, and be able to assist

Comment: I have included the html